# Decrypt value manually encrypted by SQL Server with AES 256

Tags: sql-server, encryption, aes, sql-server-2014

I would like to encrypt certain columns within my SQL Server 2014. The encryption works fine and it's easy to decrypt it within the SQL Server. The thing is now that I also want to decrypt the data outside of the server manually. I encrypted my data and tried to decrypt it with the help of some online tools but wasn't successful. Is SQL Server doing some "special" things to protect the data further? Is it possible to decrypt the data outside of the SQL Server?

Symmetric key creation:

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY topSecretKey
WITH ALGORITHM=AES_256
, IDENTITY_VALUE = 'ffoejkgeifbhkfle'
, Key_SOURCE = 'fewjgpwgdkfewjgpwgdkfewjgpwgdkfd'
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'secrEt123password';
```

`EncryptByKey` result:

```
EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('topSecretKey'), CONVERT(varchar,'this is my pw'))

--> 0x004C1D372DB0FDBE915B16664E37A3DD010000005633680204DCC53BC0CCA8F8ECC9F28A37110E7524A932F2D135CB5E83BCD615CA9DE6EB6F6530E0890990BD0E4377E3
```

I've then tried certain web tools to decrypt this value:

- Text: hex
- Mode: CBC
- IV: ffoejkgeifbhkfle
- Key Size: 256 bits
- Key: fewjgpwgdkfewjgpwgdkfewjgpwgdkfd
- Output: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Is SQL Server doing some "special" things to protect the data further? Is it possible to decrypt the data outside of the SQL Server?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any luck in getting an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hi marc_s, have you got any answer?